# checking if Facebook user is logged in using Swift and Firebase

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using this code to log the user into my app using Facebook. I have Firebase in the backend and I am using Swift 2.3

Now everyone I launch the app, I want to be able to automatically log the user in using his Facebook credentials ( unless the user explicitly logs out). Can't seem to find a way to do this ? Thanks for helping in advance.

Also just to make sure I understand this correctly, when I use Firebase and enable the Facebook login method, I don't have to handle the password storing or necessarily move them to a new account with details I get from Facebook, correct ? I can just have them log in with their Facebook credentials and not worry about the credentials etc. as I get their info (name etc) from Facebook...

```
 let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)
                let prevUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
                FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in


                    if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
                        let name = user.displayName
                        let email = user.email!
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase doesn't control (or care about) Facebook authentication status. Authenticating against Facebook simply verifies your identity, which is then used to create a Firebase credential (using `signInWithCredential`).

Thus, you can't manage, expire, renew, or maintain the Facebook token in this manner (use the Facebook SDK for that).

The Firebase credential is automatically refreshed and maintained between visits. You don't need to do anything here, other than, [as the docs indicate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), monitor for auth state changes.

On initial load, `addAuthStateDidChangeListener()` will load with the current auth status--whether the auth creds were still valid.